# Reputation Page can't add

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, profile-page

[[image: 10 + 10 + 10 + 50 = 20]

<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4b7yv.png)

Last time I checked, `10 + 10 + 10 + 50 ≠ 20`.

It survived a couple of reloads, although it's now correct.

Comment: Now it's wrong again.  It looks like a caching issue.

Comment: From an incognito window, it has a different caching issue.

Comment: I noticed this to a week ago, resolved after a few minutes.

Comment: @Dustin: It looks like a normal caching issue; the sum doesn't seem to update for about 5 minutes.  It's **extremely** annoying.

Comment: Dang. You guys weren't kidding about the long mod queue on SO.

Comment: I noticed this too. The sum result is shown in base 40 every other Wednesday.

Comment: I think you just wanted to show off you got 412 rep yesterday.

Comment: @Will: No; then, I would have shown off +440 on May 12th.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The day totals are cached for 10 minutes currently...but there's no reason can't can't add up the day's query and use that to update the totals on pre-expanded days.

You shouldn't see mismatches on pre-expanded days after the next build.  We'll update that total on page load for those few days that are shown by default (or more days if you're coming in from your profile popup, etc.)

Note: the total will still be lagged up to 10 minutes on the graph, but this is both less apparent and *needed* for sanity.