# Add thousands separator to profile reputation score

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

Here's how SLaks sees his own reputation while working (from [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91868/reputation-page-cant-add) question):

[image]
*With thousands separator*

Here's how his score looks to everyone else who visits his [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks):

[image]
*Without thousands separator*

Can we use thousands separators in the profile page score like we do in the toolbar score so that it is easier to read massive scores like that of SLaks?

Comment: IIRC, I think it was removed to save space. Let me see if I can find the question.

Comment: Hmmm... I can't find it. But I'm certain it *was* there and was subsequently removed at some point.

Comment: I know it's a little thing and if there isn't room, there isn't room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be best to slightly reduce the font size for our 29 100K users so that the comma will fit.
For 10K and 1K users, you can put in the comma without reducing the size.

Comment: When Jon Skeet finally reaches 1KK, we'll have another issue.

Comment: The `U+2009` (thin space) character would work well here and is a little more "i18n" than a comma separator. I think it should be the digit group separator for all SE. [ 123456789 ] vs [ 123 456 789 ]

Answer (score 5):

I like this better (from the [users search](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=slaks) page):

[image: Slaks results from user search]

This would easily fit into the top bar <strike>and could be printed in giant on the profile page</strike>. Perhaps with a tooltip for the actual value (exactly like on the users search page)...

**edit**  here's a screenshot:

[image: Slaks rep tooltip]

Comment: I'd be okay with the rounded version on the top bar, but I think the profile page should still display a more accurate count. There's a fair bit of difference between 140k and 140,484. I'd like to see that detail if I visit a profile page.

Comment: @Cody Gray, that sounds sensible to me as well...

Comment: @Cody: Yes.  This should not be done here.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find when it was redesigned, but now there is a thousand separator of reputation in profiles:

> [image]

Comment: I'm not sure if answering old irrelevant meta posts whose only problem is that [tag:status-completed] is missing is the right thing to do... :-/